# Duality on the symmetric algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

If we have a commutative ring $A$, and a module over $A$,  $M$, is it true that :
$$\rm{S}^{\bullet}_{A}(M^{\ast})\simeq\rm{S}^{\bullet}_{A}(M)^{\ast}?$$

Comment: What sort of dual are you taking on the outside? If you just take the dual "naively", then this will fail with any finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: I´m taking the naive dual, i.e, $\rm{Hom}_{A}(M,A)$. Why does this construction fail?

Comment: Because one side will have countable dimension while the other will have uncountable dimension.

Comment: That´s totally true, I see now... thank you Tobias.

Comment: Note that this does have an easy fix, which is to take the graded dual instead. Then at least I think you should get an isomorphism when $A$ is a field and $M$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: Hmmm that´s interesting, I have to think about it with calm